# Relation beween weak solution and classical solution .

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

For  $ f \in L^2(\Omega) $ u is called a weak solution of \begin{cases}-\Delta u=f&\text{in $\Omega$} \\ u=0&\text{in $\partial \Omega$}\end{cases}
if:

1.$u\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$

2.$\int_{\Omega}(\nabla u(x)\nabla \phi(x)-f(x)\phi(x))dx=0 $ for $\phi \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

Now to prove is :Let $\Omega \subset\mathbb{R^n} $ be a bounded domain and $\partial \Omega \in C^{\infty}$

$u \in C^2(\overline \Omega) $ is a weak solution $\Rightarrow$u is a classical solution

Can someone give me a hint , do I have to integrate 2. ?

Comment: Do you know the proof of the opposite implication: $u \in C^2(\overline \Omega)$ is a classical solution $\Longrightarrow$ $u$ is a weak solution? If yes, combine it with the [fundamental lemma of calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations).

Comment: You may want to do integration by parts

Comment: For the opposite direction I have
$-\Delta u=f \Rightarrow -\int_{\Omega}\Delta u \phi(x)dx=\int_{\Omega}f(x)\phi(x)dx$
$-\int_{\Omega}\Delta u \phi(x)dx=-\int_{\partial \Omega}\nabla u(x) \nu\phi(x)d\sigma_x+\int_{\Omega}\nabla u(x) \nabla \phi(x) dx=\int_{ \Omega}\nabla u(x) \nabla \phi(x)dx$ for $\phi \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega) .$